# after action order calls

Tags: ruby-on-rails, callback

I have a problem with the order of the calls of multiples `after_action`.

```
after_action :a, only: :create
after_action :b, only: :create
after_action :c, only: :create
```

It runs from the last to the first: `c` is the first to be called, then `b`, and finally `a`.
After some tests with `before_action`,  I have confirmed that the order is inversed.

Does someone know why?

Answer (score 0):

```
after_create :do_this,
after_create :and_then_this
```

Callbacks are generally run in the order they are defined, with the exception of callbacks defined as methods on the model, which are called last.

Refer [here](https://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/146323) also

Comment: It's not `after_create` but `after_action`

Comment: hope this helps you in case of filters 
https://blog.tahnok.me/post/filter-order-in-rails.html

Comment: @eurek this is the type of question that you don't need to ask on Stackoverflow, you just search online for the explanation. He already included 2 posts that talk about this